# Find where all locations where a constant is used in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, constants

This is quick question on an eclipse feature(can't find the answer with a quick google search)
Suppose that I have this line of code

```
public static final String NAME = "Chris";
```

I remember someone showing me an eclipse feature that allowed you to see all the places in your code that you are using this constant but I forgot what this feature is. Does anyone know how to do this real quick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the name of the variable or constant, then select References -> Workspace/Project/Hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

While your field is selected, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Windows shortcut; I don't know of what it is for mac).

Then, select "All occurrences".

That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the name of the variable (or constant), method or class and select `Open Call Hierarchy` or press shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.